# Making a foreign key referencing a table which "Has OIDs: no"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with a database which already has one table: flights. I am trying to make another table with a foreign key pointing to the table that is already there.

A `\d+ flights` command shows

```
   Column    |       Type        |                      Modifiers                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer           | not null default nextval('flights_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |  
...
Has OIDs: no
```

My create table command is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE junctiontable(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
flightid integer NOT NULL references "flights" (id), 
routeid integer NOT NULL references "routes" (id),
flightnumber integer NOT NULL
);
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "flights"
```

Can I make a table with a foreign key referencing the flights table if there is no OID?

Is it imperative that I alter the original table?

Comment: An FK must *point to* a unique row in the referenced table. `ALTER TABLE flights add primary key(id);` (or add a unique constraint) And the OID is completely unrelated here, ignore it.

Comment: That command worked and then the create table command worked afterword, thanks